# Database Design. Pivot table with 3 foreign keys or two pivot tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, design-patterns, database-design

I'm currently developing an application that allows a customer to register for an event through a custom form. That custom form will be built by the event admin for specific input by the customer.

The customer will go to the form, complete the input and pick a venue that will then display the available time-slots. I'm stuck with these two database designs and wondering which one is a better approach.

## Pivot table with 3 foreign keys

```
Table 'Customers' - 
| id | name |

Table 'Events' -
| id | name | form_fields (json)

Table 'Venues' -
| id |  address | event_id |

Table 'Timeslots' -
| id | datetime | slots | venue_id |

Pivot Table 'Tickets' -
|id | customer_id | timeslot_id | event_id | form_data (json)
```

## Two pivot tables

```
Table 'Customers' - 
| id | name |

Table 'Events' -
| id | name | form_fields (json)

Table 'Venues' -
| id |  address | event_id |

Table 'Timeslots' -
| id | datetime | slots | venue_id |

Pivot Table 'Tickets' -
| id | customer_id | timeslot_id |

Pivot Table 'EventCustomers' -
| id | customer id | event_id | form_data (json)
```

In addition, I will store the HTML markup of the custom form built by admin in 'form_fields' (json) and have the customer complete the form and store the values in 'form_data' (json).
Is it also sensible to have the custom form and data saved in json?

Thank you.

Comment: What constraints does your model have, that is the question you must ask.  Can you sell a ticket that does not have a Event? probably not.  Can you have a venue that does not host an Event, maybe.  That should dictate the relationships.  Can a venue have many events, and can an event be at many venues.  Let the requirements of the Data dictate the model.

Comment: You can think, oh it would be nice to connect this and that table.  But does it meet the requirements?  It's hard to answer without intimate knowledge of the full scope of the data.  Sometimes this is a process that we must go through to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question(even if it's a bit off topic):

**None of the above**.

To model data we must ask ourselves what are the constraints. Data is often easier to define by what it cannot do, not what it can do.

For example, can you have a Tickets record that:

- Does not have a customer record ( customer_id = null )
- Does not have a timeslot ( timeslot_id = null) -timeslot is related to venue or the location and time of the event.
- Does not have an event  ( event_id = null )

If you answered no to all of these then we have to bring this data all together at one time (but, not necessarily in the same table).

Now in my mind, it's pretty clear you could/should not have a ticket that:

- wasn't assigned to a customer
- does not have an event
- does not have a timeslot
- does not have a venue
- whose number exceeds the number of slots for the event (this you mostly missed on)

So I will assume these are our "basic" constraints

**Problems with your second case:**

- you could sell a ticket to a customer for a particular timeslot ( at a venue ), but for an unknown event.  Record in Tickets, and No record in the EventCustomers table
- you could also have a customer registered to an event, with no ticket or timeslot/venue. Record in EventCustomers and No record in the Tickets table

To me that seems somewhat illogical, and indeed it violates the constraints I outlined above.

**Problems with your first case:**

On the surface the first case looks fine as far as our constraints above look. But as I worked though it some issues popped up. To understand these, as a general rule, we always want a unique index on all the foreign keys in a pivot table ( aka a unique compound key ).

So in the first case we want this(idealy):

```
Pivot Table 'Tickets' -
|id | customer_id | timeslot_id | event_id | form_data (json)
//for this table you would want this compound, unique index
Unique Key ticket (customer_id,timeslot_id,event_id)
```

This lead me to the number of "slots" as this would imply that a customer could only have one tickets record per event and timeslot/venue. This relates back to the part I said that you mostly missed on, i.e. you have no way to track how many you have used. At first you might want to allow duplicates in this table.  "We can just add some more tickets in right?" - you think, and this is the easy fix, not.

Exhibit A:

```
Pivot Table 'Tickets' -
|id | customer_id | timeslot_id | event_id | form_data (json)
| 1 |      1      |      1      |     1    | {}
| 2 |      1      |      1      |     1    | {}
```

While contemplating `Exhibit A` consider some basic DB design rules:

In a good DB design you always want ( ideally )

- a surrogate primary key, a key with no relation to the data, this is `id`
- a natural key, a unique key that is part of the data.  An example would be if you had an email field attracted to `customer`, you could make this unique to prevent adding duplicate customers.  It's a piece of the data that is by it's nature unique and part of the data.

The first one (surrogate keys) allow you use the data with no knowledge of the data itself.  This is good as it gives us some separation of concerns, some abstractions between our code and the data.  When you join two tables on their primary key, foreign key relationship you don't need to know anything else about the data.

The second (natural key) is essential to prevent duplicate data.  In the case of a pivot table the foreign keys, which are surrogate keys in their respective tables, become a natural key in the pivot table. These are now part of the data in the context of the pivot table and they uniquely and naturally identify that data.

Why is uniqueness so important?

Once you allow duplicates with the pivot tables you will run into several issues (especially if you have accessory data like the form_data):

- How to tell those records apart?
- Which of the duplicates is the authoritative copy, which is in charge.
- How do you synchronize that accessory data, if you need to change form_data, which record do you change it in. Only one? Which one? Both? how do you maintain synchronizing all the duplicates.
- What if an accidental duplicate gets entered, how will you know it was accidental? How do you know it's a real duplicate or true duplicate and not a valid record.
- Even if you knew it was an accidental duplicat, how do you decide which one of the duplicates should be removed, this goes back to which is the authoritative record.

In short order, it really becomes a mess to deal with.

**Finally** (what I would suggest)

```
Table 'customer' - 
| id | name |

Table 'event' -
| id | name | form_fields (json)

Table 'venue' -
| id |  address | slots |

Table 'show' -
| id | datetime | venue_id | event_id | 

Table 'purchase' -
| id | show_id | customer_id | slots | created |

Table 'ticket' ( customers_shows )
| id | purchase_id | guid |
```

I changed quite a few things (you can use some or all of these changes):

I changed the plural names to singular.  I only use plurals when I do pivot tables that have a no accessory data, such a name would be `venues_events`.  This is because a record from customer is a single entity, I don't need to do any joins to get useful data.  A record from our hypothetical `venues_events` would encompass 2 entities, so I would know right away I need to do a join no matter what as there is no other data besides the foreign keys.

Now in the case of `show`, you may notice that is essentially a pivot table. So why did I not name it `venues_events` as I listed above.  The reason is we have a `datetime` column in there, which is what I mean by "accessory" data. So in this case I could pull data just from `show` if I just wanted the `datetime` and I would not need a join to do it. So it can be considered a single entity that has some Many to One relationships. ( A Many to Many is a Many to One and a One to Many that's why we need pivot tables )  More on this table later.

Letter Casing and spacing. I would suggest using all lowercase and no spaces.  MySql is case sensitive and doesn't play nice with spaces.  It's just easier from a standpoint of not having to remember did we name it `venuesEvents` or `VenuesEvents` or `Venuesevents` etc...  Consistency in naming convention is paramount in good DB design.

*The above is largely Opinion based, it's my answer so it's my opinion.  Deal with it.*

**Table show**
I moved the `slots`column to venue. I am assuming that the venue will determine how many slots are available, in my mind this is a physical requirement or attribute of the venue itself. For example a Movie theater has only X number of seats, no matter what time the movie is at doesn't change how many seats are there. If those assumptions are correct then it saves us a lot of work trying to remember how many seats a venue has every time we enter a show.

The reason I changed `timeslot` to `show` is that in both your original cases, there is some disharmony in the data model.  Some things that just don't tie together as well as they should. For example your timeslots have no direct relation to the event.

Exhibit B (using your structure):

```
Table 'event' -
| id |    name   | form_fields (json) |
| 1  | "Event A" | "{}"               |
| 2  | "Event B" | "{}"               |

 Table 'Venues' -
| id |    address   | event_id |
|  1 | "123 ABC SE" |    1     |
|  2 | "123 AB SE"  |    2     | //address entered wrong as AB instead ABC

Table 'Timeslots' -
| id |        datetime       | slots | venue_id |
| 1  | "2018-01-27 04:41:23" | 200   |    1     |
| 2  | "2018-01-27 04:41:23" | 200   |    2     |
```

In the above exhibit, we can see right away we have to duplicate the address to create more then one event at a given venue.  So if the address was entered wrong, it could be correct in some venues and incorrect in others.  This can be a real issue as programmatically how do you know that `AB` was supposed to be `ABC` when the venue ID and event ID are both different for this record. Basically how do you tell those records apart at run time?  You will find that it is very difficult to do.  The main problem is you have to much data in `Veneues`, your trying to do to much with it and the relationship doesn't fit the constraints of the data.

That's not even the worst of it as a further problem creeps in, because now that the `venue_id` is different we can corrupt our `Timeslots` table and have 2 records in there at the same time for the same venue.  Then, because the `slots` are tied to this table, we can also corrupt things down stream such as selling more tickets then we should for that time and place.  Everything just starts to fracture.

Even counting the numbers of shows at a given venue becomes a real challenge, this "flaw" is in both data models you presented.

The same Data in my Model

```
#with Unique compound Key datetime_venue_id( show.datetime, show.venue_id)

 Table 'event' -
 | id |    name   | form_fields (json) |
 | 1  | "Event A" | "{}"               |
#| 2  | "Event B" | "{}"               |

 Table 'venue' -
 | id |   address    |  slots    |
 |  1 | "123 ABC SE" |    200    |

 Table 'show' -
 | id | datetime              | venue_id | event_id | 
 | 1  | "2018-01-27 04:41:23" |   1      |    1     |
#| 2  | "2018-01-27 04:41:23" |   1      |    2     |
```

As you can see, you no longer have the duplicate address.  And while it looks like you could enter in 2 shows for the same `venue` at the same time, this is only because we don't have a compound unique key that includes the `datetime` and `venue_id` a.k.a.  `Unique Key datetime_venue_id( datetime, venue_id)`.  If you tried inserting that data with that constraint MySql would blowup on you.  And if you included both inserts ( event and show ) in the same "Transaction" (which is how I would do it, in innodb engine) the whole thing would fail and get rolled back and neither the event or show would get inserted.

Now you could try to argue that you could have the same Unique constraint on Exhibit B, but as the Venue ID is different there, you would be wrong.

*Anyway*, `show` is our new main pivot table with foreign keys from `event` and `venue` and then the accessory data `datetime`.

Besides what I went over above, this setup gives us several advantages over the old structure, in this one table we now have access to:

- what and where is the event (by joining on Table event )
- when is the event ( timestamp )
- how many slots available for the event (by joining on Table venue)

This centers everything around the `show` record. We can build a "show" independent of a customer or tickets. Because really a customer is not part of the show, and including them to soon (or to late depending how you look at it) in the data model muddies everything up.

Exhibit C

```
#in your first case
Pivot Table 'Tickets' -
|id | customer_id | timeslot_id | event_id | form_data (json)

#in your second case
Pivot Table 'Tickets' -
| id | customer_id | timeslot_id |

Pivot Table 'EventCustomers' -
| id | customer id | event_id | form_data (json)
```

AS I said above, you cant put what I am calling a `show` the what,where and when together without having a customer ID (in either of your data models).  As you build your application around this later it will become a huge issue.  This may be insurmountable at run time.  Basically, you need all that data assembled and waiting on the customer_id. In both of your models that's not the case, and there is data you may not have easy access to.  For example for the first case (of the old structure) how would you know that `timeslot_id=20` AND `event_id=32` plus a customer equals a valid ticket?  There is no direct relationship between `timeslot` and `event` outside of the pivot table that contains the customer. `timeslot_id=20` could be valid for any event and you have no way to know that.

It's so much easier to grab say `show=32` and check how many slots are left and then just do the purchase record.  Everything is ready and waiting for it.

**Table purchase**
I also added purchase or an order table, even if the "shows" are free this table provides us with some great utility. This is also a pivot table, but it has some accessory data just like show does. ( `slots` and `created` ).

This table

- we bind the customer table to the show table here
- we have a 'created' field so you will know when this record was created, when the tickets where purchased
- we also have a number of slots the customer will use, we can do an aggregate sum of `slots` grouped on the `show_id` to see how many slots we have "sold". With one join from `show` to `venue` we can find out how many total slots this "show" has with the same integer key (show.id) that we used above to aggregate.  Then it would be a simple matter to compare the two, if you wanted to get fancy you may be able to do this all in one query.

**Table ticket**
Now you may or may not even need this table. It has a many to one relationship to table purchase.  So One `order` can have Many `tickets`.  The records in here would be generated when a purchase is made, the number dependent on what is in slots.  The primary use of this table is just to provide a unique record for each individual ticket. For this I have `guid` column which can just be a unique hash.  Basically this would give you some tracking ability on individual tickets, I don't really have enough information to know how this will work in your case. You may even be able to replace this table with JSON data if searching on it is not a concern, and that would make maintenance of it easier in the case that some tickets are refunded.  But as I hinted this is very dependent on your particular use case.

Some brief SQL examples

Joining Everything (just to show the relationships):

```
SELECT
    {some fields}
FROM
    ticket AS t
JOIN
    puchase AS p ON t.purchase_id = p.id
JOIN    
    customer AS c ON p.customer_id = c.id
JOIN
    show AS s ON p.show_id = s.id
JOIN
    venue AS v ON s.venue_id = s.id
JOIN
    event AS e ON s.event_id = e.id
```

Counting the used slots for a show:

```
SELECT
    SUM(slots) AS used_slots
FROM
    puchase
WHERE
    show_id = :show_id
GROUP BY show_id
```

Get the available slots for a show:

```
SELECT
    v.name,
    v.slots
FROM
    venue AS v
JOIN
    show AS s ON s.venue_id = v.id
WHERE
    v.show_id = :show_id
    # or you could do s.id = :show_id
```

It also works out nice that all the tables start with a different letter, which makes aliasing a bit easier.

**-note-** The table name `event` may be a reserved word in MySql, I am not sure off the top of my head if it will work as a table name.  Some reserved words still work in some parts of the query based on the context it's used in.  Even if that is true, I am sure you can come up with a work around for it.  Coincidentally this is why I named `purchase` that instead of `order` as "order" is a reserved word. (I just happen to think of event)

I hope that helps and makes sense.  I probably spent way more time on this then I should have, but I design things like this for a living and I really enjoy the data architecture part of it, so I can get a bit carried away at times.